# Getting a factor error when aggregating a table but no columns are factors

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

So I have my data uploaded from a csv file. I tried uploading it with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` but I still got the error. First 13 columns are stings, the remaining columns (14 onwards) are all numeric. Here is the core code:

```
library("readxl")

# Read data with facotr is False 
data <- read.csv("PFR csvData.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Convert all numeric rows to numeric
data[,14:length(colnames(data))]<- as.numeric(as.character(unlist(data[,14:length(colnames(data))])))

# Convert all string rows to characters
data[,1:13]<- as.character(unlist(data[,1:13]))
```

When I check the class of every column through `sapply(data, class)` I get:

```
           Rk           Player              Pos              Age             Date               Lg               Tm 
     "character"      "character"      "character"      "character"      "character"      "character"      "character" 
             H.A              Opp           Result               G.             Week              Day    Receiving_Tgt 
     "character"      "character"      "character"      "character"      "character"      "character"        "numeric" 
   Receiving_Rec    Receiving_Yds    Receiving_Y.R     Receiving_TD  Receiving_Ctch.  Receiving_Y.Tgt    Receiving_PPR 
       "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric" 
     Passing_Cmp      Passing_Att     Passing_Cmp.      Passing_Yds       Passing_TD      Passing_Int     Passing_Rate 
       "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric" 
      Passing_Sk   Passing_Sk_Yds      Passing_Y.A     Passing_AY.A      Passing_PPR      Rushing_Att      Rushing_Yds 
       "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric" 
     Rushing_Y.A       Rushing_TD Rushing_Half_PPR   Total_Half_PPR 
       "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"
```

I also checked for NAs through `apply(data, 2, function(x) any(is.na(x)))` and obtained:

```
              Rk           Player              Pos              Age             Date               Lg               Tm 
           FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE 
             H.A              Opp           Result               G.             Week              Day    Receiving_Tgt 
           FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE 
   Receiving_Rec    Receiving_Yds    Receiving_Y.R     Receiving_TD  Receiving_Ctch.  Receiving_Y.Tgt    Receiving_PPR 
           FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE 
     Passing_Cmp      Passing_Att     Passing_Cmp.      Passing_Yds       Passing_TD      Passing_Int     Passing_Rate 
           FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE 
      Passing_Sk   Passing_Sk_Yds      Passing_Y.A     Passing_AY.A      Passing_PPR      Rushing_Att      Rushing_Yds 
           FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE 
     Rushing_Y.A       Rushing_TD Rushing_Half_PPR   Total_Half_PPR 
           FALSE            FALSE            FALSE            FALSE
```

So at this point, I think I uploaded my data without factors, ensure that all columns are not factors by coercing their types, and double check by looking at the class of each column. I also made sure there are no NAs

However, when I use my aggreating function, I get an error related to factors:

```
aggregate(data$Player, by = list(data$Total_Half_PPR), FUN = sum)
Error in Summary.factor(291L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

I am not sure what else to do. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Player' is `factor`.  We need to convert to `numeric`

```
data$Player <- as.numeric(as.character(data$Player))
```

---

If we need to get the `sum` of 'Total_Half_PPR', do this the other way

```
aggregate(data$Total_Half_PPR, by = list(data$Player), FUN = sum)
```

or using the formula method

```
aggregate(Total_Half_PPR ~ Player, data, FUN = sum)
```

Comment: So that worked, but not as intended. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the use of aggregate. What I'm trying to get is the sum of my column "Total Half PPR" for each player - i.e Player A - 300, Player B - 200 and so on. If I convert player to numeric I lose the actual player name. Any suggestions as to how to get to what I'm looking for, which is just the equivalent of the following in SQL: select player, sum(Total_Half_PPR) from table group by player

Comment: @scunden  It is the other way;  Please check the update